# Maximum quantity don't work in Ajax Cart WooCommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have one product on which I set up the maximum quantity value for an order. Everything works well on the product page and in the cart, but I also have a pop-up ajax cart, when opening which I can increase the quantity of this product in the order. Limits don't work for ajax cart.
Here all code from my ajax cart https://repl.it/@KulikovkaKyKi/Example#main.php

The file is located here:

```
/wp-content/themes/caring/functions/genericfunctions/Generic_Class_Mini_Ajax_Cart.php
```

I see that the value of the variable $max_qty_allowed is always int(-1), also in the input to the max value, I need to transfer data, but I can't get the maximum value in any way.

Instead of this code:

```php
<input type="hidden" name="maxstock" class="maxstock-<?php echo $values['data']->get_id(); ?>" value="<?php echo $max_value; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cartkey" class="cartkey-<?php echo $values['data']->get_id(); ?>" value="<?php echo $item;?>">
<button type="button" data-id="<?php echo $values['data']->get_id(); ?>" class="sub minicart-qty-minus float-left">-</button>
<input name="minicart-quantity" id="minicart-quantity" class="float-left qty-<?php echo $values['data']->get_id(); ?>" type="text" readonly="true"  value="<?php echo $values['quantity'];?>" min="1" max="" />
<button type="button" data-id="<?php echo $values['data']->get_id(); ?>" class="add minicart-qty-plus float-left">+</button>
```

I tried to write the next code:

```php
woocommerce_quantity_input( $max_value, $values['data'], true );
```

And it works, but when I increase the quantity of some product in the ajax cart, then close the card and reopen the values return to the old ones. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please include the specific PHP code, logs, errors, and any relevant information within the question itself as opposed to having people link elsewhere.

Comment: @fth there is a lot of code so I put it elsewhere